# how to keep special characters using preg_replace in php

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to use `preg_replace` function and it works as expected. The problem is it also removes the special alphabet like this one `Ö` and removes `O`. How can I keep `Ö`?

```
$string='GÖTEBORG-SEASON-1';
echo $str=preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z-_]/', '', $string);
```

It output `GTEBORG-SEASON-` (`Ö is missing`) but I am expecting `GÖTEBORG-SEASON-`

Thank you.

Comment: Is every string you want to replace like this? Because then, you could just use `substr()` and only remove the last character. Else `preg_replace('/\d/', '', $string);` comes to mind if you only want to remove digits. Please be more clear what you want to achieve.

Comment: Does this also happen when you use the RegExp ``'/[^A-Za-z_-]/'``?

Comment: Use [mb_ereg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-ereg-replace.php) with multibyte support.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have solved it. I need to use something like this 
`preg_replace ('/[^\p{L}-_]/u','', $string);`